# Стоит ли использовать разные языки для первого проекта?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать первый нормальный проект с целью обучения основам пайтон и вообще прогинга. Использовать стандартную библиотеку и консоль честно нет никакого желания(предлагали сделать тетрис, но порыскав в инете понял что стандартной библиотекой не обойтись), хочется что то более полезное хотя бы для себя. Ранее делал бота для дискорд, и даже была фича когда можно было писать от имени бота(с кучей костылей, но я очень был рад тому что спустя 4 часа смог это сделать). После решил похожее сделать на телеграм боте, где ждало разочарование в виде непонятной документации и отсутствия видео по основам API.
Сейчас решил уйти с питоном в WEB, ибо не знаю куда его ещё пихнуть. Придётся учить и другие языки, и я к этому готов, но стоит ли оно того, стоит ли идти в Web если до этого только HTML в школе учил? Мои знания пайтон дошли до знания структур данных и частично ООП(без проекта и практики вряд ли его можно выучить)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `JavaScript` в любом случае придётся учить для веба

Comment: понимаю что JS понадобится, но это лучше же чем топтаться на месте с Python?

Comment: @lattuse На мой взгляд лучше пойти вместе с питоном в Data Science, но это нужно знать много помимо программирования - линейную алгебру и теорию вероятностей как минимум. Data Science - очень интересная и весьма хорошо оплачиваемая область, но к ней нужно иметь способности и желание туда развиваться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря что ты имеешь ввиду под "идти в веб". Если хочешь стать фулстак разработчиком - без HTML, CSS, JS не обойтись.
Если просто бекенд - нужен только пайтон.
А если ты хочешь самостоятельно сделать простенький сайт в качестве пет-проекта(с бекендом и фронтендом), тебе хватит пайтон + HTML